Specify a GPG key as Identity for ssh host
I am troubleshooting access to SSH server (vendor's server, not mine). I have an rsa4096 GPG key with passphrase and with Authentication subkey. I exported the ssh-key for the subkey, double checked that it is the correct one, and sent it but I am unable to access the server.
I added authentication keygrip to ~/.gnupg/sshcontrol, added enable-ssh-support to ~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf, and use-agent to ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf. I also added the following to my .bashrc
export GPG_TTY="$(tty)"
export SSH_AUTH_SOCK=$(gpgconf --list-dirs agent-ssh-socket)
gpgconf --launch gpg-agent

For troubleshooting, I used the verbose option and noticed that all my added authentication keys and the non existent ./.ssh/id_* keys are attempted. I wanted to specify which key to be used for authentication by specifying IdentitiesOnly and IdentityFile options in ~/.ssh/config for their host. So I tried 2 things:

Export private subkey using gpg and add its path as IdentiyFile. That didn't work with "error in libcrypto". I read it is something to do with formatting where gpg is not immediately compatible with ssh keys.
Export public key (tried both armored and unaromored) using gpg and add its path as IdentiyFile. That didn't work either and the logs show the same "error in libcrypto". Strangely enough, they indicate that it is being attempted as a private key.


debug1: Trying private key: /home/me/.ssh/gpg.pub


I can't rule out that the vendor made an error with registering my keys, but I can't rule out that I didn't do anything wrong either. Any idea?
I use gpg 2.2.27


Export public key (tried both armored and unaromored) using gpg and add its path as IdentiyFile. That didn't work

It didn't work because the two programs use completely different key formats – PGP key files will not be automatically understood by non-PGP software.
You need to export the public key in OpenSSH format, i.e. the same way that you've previously done to extract the 'ssh-rsa' string for uploading to the server.
You can use ssh-add -L to get all public keys currently in the agent, or just copy the key back from the server's authorized_keys to a local id_foo.pub file.

Thank you that solved the error in specifying the identity.
